# Get owner from PDA if the owner is off-curve - DAS API

Tags: solana-program, rust, metaplex, geyser

Is it somehow possible to get and deserialize the owner of the token account if the owner is a PDA and off-curve around this line - https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/digital-asset-rpc-infrastructure/blob/main/nft_ingester/src/program_transformers/token/mod.rs#L34 without initializing a `RpcClient`?

And if not, then is it possible to pass a `RpcClient` to the function? Or how else can I achieve it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There's no way to do this on the existing DAS providers, you'll have to fork and run your own validator for this, which is not an easy task. Are you prepared to do that?

Comment: Yes I am @KartikSoneji , I already forked the DAS RPC Infra and am ready to update with help if possible.

Comment: OK, since you're running a validator, you won't need an rpc client to fetch account info, you should be able to query your local database. But before that, there might be an easier way by using an instruction parser https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/digital-asset-rpc-infrastructure/blob/600a711c09e5024c48ad83138a0ded5d989138cd/nft_ingester/src/program_transformers/mod.rs#L89

Comment: This question unfortunately does not have a simple answer, if you want to work together to find a solution for your specific use case then please feel free to contact me on email/discord (@kartiksoneji)

Comment: Not really. I'm trying to find out what will be the best way to achieve this. Do I need to create `RpcClient` and pass to the functions and use it to get the wallet data then deserialize? 

Or is there any other way to get the account data?

Comment: That really depends on how the staking program works. Like I said before, since you are running a local database, you won't need an RPC client. You might be able to use an instruction listener instead of an account listener to track movements.

Comment: The ingester doesn't work that way does it? I think it parses tokens accounts and saves the data in database, and then uses that info of token account from db to form the asset data.